# How to disable Google Sign-In, coming with Firebase pods?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I don't wanna use Google Sign-In, I did only pod install Firebase. Now I can't open my app with below error. How Can I disable it, I couldn't find a way.

> Error: URL scheme needed for Google Sign-In not included in your app's
>   Info.plist. Please refer to the Google Sign-In SDK documentation for
>   more information.'

Comment: Can you post your whole Podfile? Particularly, check whether you have the Google pod in there (perhaps for Google Analytics)? The error could be coming from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deintegrate the pods and then install them again following all steps in the Firebase tutorial.

When you say pod install Firebase which pod are you specifically talking about?

https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-deintegrate

Answer (score 1):

This problem needs to add a URL scheme for your reversed client ID. 
To find this value, open the GoogleService-Info.plist configuration file, and look for the REVERSED_CLIENT_ID key. 
Copy the value of that key, and paste it into the URL Schemes box on the configuration page. Leave the other fields blank.

you can see this link:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating